# How to delay route change in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have a master/detail view app, when users go back from detail to master view, I'd like to take a screenshot of the *detail* view using html2canvas The problem is that html2canvas provides only async methods for screen capturing, so I need to hold the route change until the capture is done, then resume, how can I do this?

Comment: Does `html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    /* whatever you do with the canvas */; $location.path('/next-route');
});` not accomplish that?

Comment: can prevent route change if needed within `$routeChangeStart` event and use flag to make sure you have what you need before proceeding

Comment: I may have a solution, but depends on your current implementation. Can you post your code for controller and html?

Comment: @BennettAdams If the user goes back to main view via the browser's Back button, then there's nowhere to put this code, I think I have to listen to route change events, hold the change, take capture, then resume.